# Gnuplot - can't make image working remotely

Tags: gnuplot

I try to make image remotely. I use  Windows 7 and work remotely on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 by using WinSCP and Putty. I write in terminal

```
gnuplot
```

then (and this part work when I work not remotely and everything is ok, this is not work only when I work remotely)

```
plot './box_dopc.xvg' u ($1/1000):(($2*$3)/64*100) w l notitle; set xlabel 'czas [ns]'; set ylabel 'Srednie pole pow. na lipid [A^2]';set term png large size 800,600;set output 'pole.png';replot;exit
```

Then I have an error

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

I just want to make an image in gnuplot, no need to display.

This is part of my input file

```
#
# Giant Rising Ordinary Mutants for A Clerical Setup
#
@    title "Gromacs Energies"
@    xaxis  label "Time (ps)"
@    yaxis  label "E (kJ mol\S-1\N)"
@TYPE xy
@ view 0.15, 0.15, 0.75, 0.85
@ legend on
@ legend box on
@ legend loctype view
@ legend 0.78, 0.8
@ legend length 2
@ s0 legend "Box-X"
@ s1 legend "Box-Y"
@ s2 legend "Box-Z"
    0.000000    9.000000    9.000000    7.500000
    1.000000    8.933211    8.892943    7.155660
    2.000000    8.752816    8.712972    7.093182
    3.000000    8.611457    8.592942    7.114618
    4.000000    8.522141    8.501667    7.137370
    5.000000    8.435238    8.455355    7.189497
    6.000000    8.383215    8.403980    7.146751
    7.000000    8.306597    8.345073    7.182563
    8.000000    8.282993    8.312009    7.240950
    9.000000    8.205981    8.237565    7.298838
   10.000000    8.146607    8.189069    7.347158
   11.000001    8.082211    8.177455    7.364603
```

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to just make image without show them? My students need to use only ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I found an answer, I just delete replot and change order

```
set xlabel 'czas [ns]'; set ylabel 'Srednie pole pow. na lipid [A^2]';set term png large size 800,600;set output 'pole.png'; plot './box_dopc.xvg' u ($1/1000):(($2*$3)/64*100) w l notitle; exit
```